# When was Progress DB 9.1 and 9.1D released?

Tags: openedge, progress-db

I have an old application that I manage that runs on top of a progress database.  I'm trying to gather some information, for various reasons.  At a minimum, I need to know when Progress 9.1 and 9.1D were released.  I mention these two versions because we are using 9.1D and, I assume, the "D" revision is probably just the fourth iteration in miner updates since the initial release of 9.1.

Optimally, I'd like to find a source-link to a Progress DB change log.  However, questions for documentation aren't typically acceptable around here.  Instead, I'm asking for the date these versions were released and requesting that you provide a source that I can explore further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

9.1A was 1999, 9.1D was 2002.

9.1E SP04, the very last release of version 9, was released in 2004.

With version 10 the product name changed to "OpenEdge".  Which is much easier to google than "progress" ;)

If you actually have a given release of Progress installed you can look in the "version" file.  It will tell you what the build date was.

For a general idea: http://www.oehive.org/VersionHistory